# React Navigation, how to navigate StackNavigator from parent view?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have issue with React-Navigation by try to access/remote children to navigate StackNavigator.

Below is my code sample:

```
const StackIndex = StackNavigator({
    Screen1: {
        screen: Screen1
    },
    Screen2: {
        screen: Screen2
    },
    Screen3: {
        screen: Screen3
    }
})


class TabIndex extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')}>
                    <Text>{'Navigate to Screen 2.'}<Text>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <StackIndex />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

> Here is my project testing: [TestReactNavigation](https://github.com/sseyha/TestNavigation)

Please help...

Comment: You haven't actually said what your "issue" is!  Is nothing happening at all?  Are there any errors that you can see?

Comment: try delete `this.props.` in `onPress TouchableWithoutFeedback` so the `onPress` will `onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Screen2')}`

Comment: it's appear Undefined navigation.

Comment: @ChillyPenguin
Here is my project related to this issue.
https://github.com/sseyha/TestNavigation

Comment: @flix
Here is my project testing 
https://github.com/sseyha/TestNavigation